# Joomla extension which can allow an end-user to upload a spreadsheet

Tags: joomla-3.x, php

1. Is there any Joomla extension which can allow an end-user to upload a spreadsheet which can be viewed on the website running Joomla 3.4.1 as http://www.acsf.cornell.edu/education/curricula/
2. If not, I understand there may be PHP libraries/parsers which can take spreadsheet as an input and display its contents. Which ones integrate well with Joomla?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this would work for you? https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_place_a_copy_of_an_Excel_worksheet_on_to_your_web_site_for_viewing_only Maybe this too http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/ari-docs-viewer

Comment: Side note: Not sure if you heard the news, but Joomla 3.4.5 patches a massive security risk. If you're on Joomla less than this version, please update **immediately**

Comment: Thanks johnny_s, The spreadsheet data needs to be sortable, but I will try the methods you suggested. Thank you for the links.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried uploading the Excel to the site and then placing it in an iFrame?  (menu type = system-wrapper) You would want to save it with Read Only privileges, etc.  You could also do the iframe in a module.

Another option would be to convert to GDocs and load that iFrame.